# How to retrieve index of current item in for_each loop?

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create ingress rules with an incrementing rule_no inside a for_each loop:

```
resource "aws_default_network_acl" "default" {
  ...

  # allow client machine to have full access to all hosts

  ingress {
    protocol   = "-1"
    rule_no    = 100
    action     = "allow"
    cidr_block = "${var.primary_client_cidr_block}"
    from_port  = 0
    to_port    = 0
  }

  # additional_client_cidr_blocks example [ "x.x.x.x/32", "y.y.y.y/32", ... ] 
  # where x and y are replaced with actual IP addresses

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.additional_client_cidr_blocks

    content {
      protocol   = "-1"
      rule_no    = 101 + ingress.index
      action     = "allow"
      cidr_block = ingress.value
      from_port  = 0
      to_port    = 0
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

The error is:

> 117:       rule_no    = 101 + ingress.index
>
> This object does not have an attribute named "index".

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `index` with `key` should work. From the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks):

> `key` is the map key or list element index for the current element. If the `for_each` exression produces a set value then `key` is identical to `value` and should not be used.